# Grounded Reference Power Supply Output Problem

Tags: power-supply, power, grounding, protection

I have several cabinets. Each cabinet have 24V power supply that has option to select ground reference output or floating reference output. Please look at the picture, at the bottom of power supply, you will see jumper between GND and Protective Earth.
[image]

If I connect the GND to PE for all cabinet, Will it be a problem to other cabinet if one of a cabinet, for example cabinet 3, got electrical failure?

Comment: What is ‘electrical failure’? Is it no mains input? If so, loss of mains on one cabinet would no affect other cabinets? What led you to think there might be a problem? Consider all the electrical equipment in your house - how are they wired any different to your cabinets?

Comment: No. Next question.

Comment: It will be a problem if the PE fault trips the main distribution breaker.

Comment: What failure you mean? It might be a problem without a failure too. You might have created a ground loop, depending on how other connections are between racks

Comment: Bonding to PE is never a *safety* problem. However stuff could stop working :D a more detailed analysis is needed, included the potential differences between cabinets

Answer (score 1):

It is standard practice to connect the common terminal of a DC power supply to protective earth, with safety in mind.

A 24 V DC line is considered safe to touch. Should the DC common not be earthed, a user would be unaware of the lurking danger in the event of the DC bus coming in contact with a high voltage line. In such an event, an earthed DC common would ensure that a fuse blows or a breaker trips in the high voltage circuit to render it safe.

With the DC common not earthed, short circuits to earth in the DC circuit could cause malfunctioning of the equipment. In such a case, an earthed DC common would ensure that a fuse-blow or a breaker-trip in the DC circuit renders it safe.

> If I connect the GND to PE for all cabinet, Will it be a problem to other cabinet if one of a cabinet, for example cabinet 3, got electrical failure?

Faults in one panel would certainly not affect other panels just because the DC commons are earthed.